# Pull Image from Server Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am attempting to pull an image from the server side to the client side. I store the file path in mySQL, and I am able to pull the file to react js as a url, but the image will not load. Below is the code for the front end, React Js, and back end, Node Js. Any advice will do. Thank you in advance!

React Js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './NewsAndFlyers.css';
//Components
import Header from '../../Components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../../Components/Footer/Footer';
//Repositories
import Axios from 'axios';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const NewsAndFlyers = () => {
    const [newsData, setNewsData] = useState([]);
    const [FlyersData, setFlyersData] = useState([]);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        getFlyerProps();
        setIsLoading(false);
    }, []);

    const getFlyerProps = async () => {
        //Get the data from the api
        await Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/Flyer/Flyer_Retrieval')
        //Convert data to json
        .then((response) =>  {
        setFlyersData(response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header/>
            <div className='newsAndFlyersBody'>
                <h1 className='newsHeader'>News</h1>
                <a href='/NewsAndFlyers/Upload'><button className='uploadButton'>Upload</button></a>
                <h1 className='flyerHeader'>Flyers</h1>
                {FlyersData.map((flyer) => (
                    <>
                        <img src={ flyer.flyerURL } alt="" />
                        <h1>{ flyer.flyerName }</h1>
                        <p>{ flyer.flyerEventDate }</p>
                        <p>{ flyer.flyerDescription }</p>
                    </>
                ))}
            </div>
            <Footer/>
        </>
    );
}

export default NewsAndFlyers;
```

Node Js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const db = require('../config/db');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const SqlDbStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//----------------------------------------- BEGINNING OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(session({
    key: 'session_cookie_name',
    secret: 'session_cookie_secret',
    store: new SqlDbStore({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
    database: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie:{
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24,
        secure: false
    }
}));
const flyerDestination = './FlyerFiles'
const flyerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb){ 
    return cb(null, flyerDestination)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    return cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
const flyerUpload = multer({ storage: flyerStorage }).array('files');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/Flyer_Upload', (req, res) => {
  flyerUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    const flyerName = req.body.flyerName;
    const flyerEventDate = req.body.flyerEventDate;
    const flyerDescription = req.body.flyerDescription;
    const flyerID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    const flyerDirectory = 'http://localhost:3001/Flyer/';

    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err)
    }
    
    for (const file of req.files) {
      directory = path.dirname(file.path);
      const flyerUploadedPath = flyerDirectory + file.filename
      
      db.query('INSERT INTO flyerinfo (flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerURL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerUploadedPath], (err, res) => {
        if (err){
          return res.json({message: 'An Error Occurred!' });
        }
      });
      return res.status(200).send(req.files);
    }
  });
});

router.post('/Flyer_Retrieval', express.static('public'), (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM flyerinfo ORDER BY flyerIDTracker DESC', (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;    
    res.send(results);
  });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Do you have a folder public in your root project? Because in your code you defined the file path public  `express.static('public')`

Comment: I do not, I will test and see if that works

Comment: Inside the public folder, you need to put all your stored images that you want to pull from front-end

Comment: Can it be a folder path that leads to a sub folder or does it have to be just public?

Comment: your images should be present either in the public folder  or it's sub folders

Comment: So that means the file path would be express.static(‘public/FlyerInfos’)?

Comment: Or would it still be public?

Comment: It should be public but inside the public folder you can have multiple subdirectories, if the image is stored inside the subdirectory URL should be like `localhost:3001/subdirectory/filename,` and if the image stored inside the public directory, and is not in the subdirectory then the URL should be `localhost:3001/<filename>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the two following lines in my server index.js file.

```
app.use('/public/FlyerFiles', express.static('public/FlyerFiles'));
app.use('/public/TeamMembersFiles', express.static('public/TeamMembersFiles'));
```

Once these were added, I was able to upload the images to the folder with the following code below.

```
const flyerDestination = './public/FlyerFiles/'
const flyerStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb){ 
    return cb(null, flyerDestination)
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb){
    return cb(null, file.originalname);
  }
});
const flyerUpload = multer({ storage: flyerStorage }).array('files');
//----------------------------------------- END OF PASSPORT MIDDLEWARE AND SETUP ---------------------------------------------------
router.post('/Flyer_Upload', (req, res) => {
  flyerUpload(req, res, function (err) {
    const flyerName = req.body.flyerName;
    const flyerEventDate = req.body.flyerEventDate;
    const flyerDescription = req.body.flyerDescription;
    const flyerID = Math.floor(Math.random()*90000) + 10000;
    const flyerDirectory = 'http://localhost:3001/public/FlyerFiles/';

    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return res.status(500).json(err)
    } else if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json(err)
    }
    
    for (const file of req.files) {
      directory = path.dirname(file.path);
      const flyerUploadedPath = flyerDirectory + file.filename
      
      db.query('INSERT INTO flyerinfo (flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerURL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)', [flyerID, flyerName, flyerEventDate, flyerDescription, flyerUploadedPath], (err, res) => {
        if (err){
          return res.json({message: 'An Error Occurred!' });
        }
      });
      return res.status(200).send(req.files);
    }
  });
});
```

And now I can retrieve them with everything on the front end being the same.

```
router.post('/Flyer_Retrieval', (req, res) => {
  db.query('SELECT * FROM flyerinfo ORDER BY flyerIDTracker DESC', (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;    
    res.send(results);
  });
});
```